# Size of 1 stack allocated by .maxstack 1

Tags: .net, il

When I say `.maxstack 1`, how does it work? Can I push **any datatype** onto the stack? How does it decide the size for the stack. Is it done prematurely, or at runtime?

**Edit1:** Even when I push only one argument on the stack,how does it decide the ***memory allocation*** for it?Is its data type identified at ***compile time or run time***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any type. It it the number of *items* to reserve space for on the stack. This is more for verification than for space, as far as I can tell - because as you note different types require different amounts of space (oversized structs, for example).

1 may be a bit low in most cases, though.

Comment: I know that it will reserve space for one argument.Check Edit1

Comment: @Pavitar if I take your meaning - the maxstack will probably be checked during verification (or PEVerify if you want to do it outside of the runtime). Beyond that, any further use of this is up to the JIT (or NGEN if you are doing eager JIT)

Comment: @Pavitar you hadn't when I replied ;p As per my comment above, it will be up to JIT/NGEN (or AOT on mono); most commonly the JIT (i.e. runtime). This counts doubly for generics, since generic methods are JITted once per value type and 1 once (only) for all reference types, to account for size difference (the above is per combination of arguments in the case of multi-generic methods)